# GetOrgChart Mouse Movement Broken In Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, getorgchart

I am trying to get the latest version of GetOrgChart working for my company website, but the latest version on their website does not work properly in Firefox and Chrome. The mouse scrolling and movement doesn't work, but it works fine in IE. I found a working version using Way Back Machine from last year, but when comparing the two there were too many changes, and I don't know enough about JavaScript to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am using GetOrgChart  version 2.4.8
I had a similar problem with the movement and the arrows didn't work or shown on some machines despite of  using the same version of chrome. but if you updated the getorgchart.js file specifically the below code, the problem will be solved.
So search for this code block and change it from

```
if (this.config.enableMove) {
        if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
            this._q(this._X._t, "touchstart", this._y, "canvasContainer");
            this._q(this._X._t, "touchmove", this._b, "canvasContainer");
            this._q(this._X._t, "touchend", this._g, "canvasContainer")
        } else {
            this._q(this._X._zr, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._am, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._Q, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._zB, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mousemove", this._aA);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mousedown", this._aQ);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mouseup", this._aZ);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mouseleave", this._aZ)
       }
    }
```

Into:

```
if (this.config.enableMove) {
            this._q(this._X._zr, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._am, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._Q, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._zB, "mousedown", this._aS);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mousemove", this._aA);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mousedown", this._aQ);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mouseup", this._aZ);
            this._q(this._X._t, "mouseleave", this._aZ)
       }
```